# Date time input being inserted at 0000-00-00 00:00:00 with Laravel 5

Tags: datetime, laravel-5, timestamp

using a date time picker and it keeps inserting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 into my TIMESTAMP 'time' field.

When printing out the requested input it shows:

```
04/08/2016 12:00 AM
```

What do I need to do to allow that to be inserted correctly into my database?

Comment: I'm not sure.. but, I think you could setup this field as "date" , check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date you are using in the input is in the incorrect format for MySQL.

Before inserting the date into the database, convert it into a compatible format, e.g.:

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $request->input('date') ) );
```

This assumes your input field is called `date` (please change accordingly). The above code coverts the date from your input field into a unix timestamp, and then formats it to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.